# Unexpected 404's on some of the static recourses PDF and Zip

Tags: http-status-code-404, iis-8

I have an MVC website developed in dotnet 4.5 and is hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS Server 8.5.

We are experiencing a weird behavior on our website while trying to hit a page with static resources mainly when accessing a PDF and Zip file. There is a link on the website that redirects user to see the PDF file and user sees 404 not found, please keep in mind that file is there and path is also correct, but once you **hit the URL from the browser directly you can download the file** with no issue.

[image]

[image]

FYI, the permission are there and also MEME Types are Enabled.

I have tried again, having an eye inspect the element's network tab and I find out 200 Status response but the content was also 404 Not found.

[image]

[image]

Note: As per our IT team there is no NGINX installed on the server.

Comment: Note that the 404 errors shown are from nginx. If you don't explain clearly why nginx is involved, no further discussion can be made.

Comment: Thanks @KJ, actually, It does not return the actual data but instead of the actual PDF I received the HTML containing 404 not found nginx.

Comment: @KJ I have no idea about that, is it something I can check? As per our IT team there is no involvement of it. but not sure why I have to see this.

Comment: You can try using the failed request tracker to view the detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.